# Print the message of a response header on screen

Tags: php, ajax, error-handling, http-headers, httpresponse

I am trying to send a custom response header from my web server to the browser and to print its *reason phrase* on the screen. Unfortunately this does not happen.

My goal is to set an error handler (here: `errorHandler`) to display a user-friendly message to the user in all cases when an error is raised. So, not only when there is a "normal" HTTP request, but even if the request to the server is an ajax request.

In the case of an ajax request, by doing this, I can, already, trigger the corresponding ajax "error" callback and print the *reason phrase* of the header in there, if an error occurs. But in the case of a "normal" request, like below, this doesn't work. E.g. no message is printed on the screen.

Could you tell me, why not, and how I can solve this problem?

Thank you.

---

**handlers.php:**

```
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);

set_error_handler('errorHandler');

function errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 420 An error occurred during your request. Please try again, or contact us.');
    error_log('Error ' . $errno . ' - ' . $errstr . ' in file ' . $errfile . ' on line ' . $errline);
    exit();
}
```

**index.php:**

```
<?php

require 'handlers.php';

// Because the function test() doesn't exist, an error is thrown.
// But I see no message on screen.
$tmnlid = test();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you get no message printed on the screen is because a browser only displays the body of the HTTP message.
Your current `errorHandler()` produces an empty body, therefore nothing on screen.

If you want the browser to show the error message, you have to put the error message in the body by `echo`-ing it.
Thus, your `errorHandler()` should look like this example:

```
function errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 420 Custom error message');
    echo 'Custom error message';
    exit();
}
```

Note that the `error_log()` line is removed for simplicity.
Of course, you should wrap the error message with appropriate HTML if you want to make it user-friendly.

Comment: This is a beautiful answer. And it works great. Thank you, Rei!